# Sending shared preference to other device on android application,possible?

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, preference

Currently i am developing a walkie talkie android application program using eclipse.
What i want to build is to create a room(channel) and then set a password to it, and then store a password in preference.And i would like to send this preference to other device and update that device preference.I would like to know if this is possible? and if its possible would you like to tell me how it works?

any help is appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: If you can transfer speach between two devices then i wonder why you would have problems transfering some strings. As that is all what you have to do. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to communicate between devices while they're not physically connected. This can be through SMS, Custom Web Servers, PAAS such as Parse or Kinvey. You can also look at technologies such as MQTT to do this for you. Services for this also exist, such as: Octoblu